# Which Android Target supports Safari or Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, android-emulator, safari

I'm trying to run an app on an Android Emulator and in the current Target I'm using the animations stop working - but I think it's just because neither Safari nor Google Chrome aren't supported in the target I'm using (it's 4.1.2). Is there a target which does support either of these?

Thanks a lot in advance xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the Google chrome specification it will work on android 4.0 and above so you should try it on mobile.